# Complicated double sum using groupby in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, sklearn-pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like

```
Race_ID   Date           Student_ID      a   b     
1         1/1/2023       1               3   1   
1         1/1/2023       2               2   2   
1         1/1/2023       3               1   4    
1         1/1/2023       4               4   1   
2         11/9/2022      1               2   6   
2         11/9/2022      2               3   2   
2         11/9/2022      3               1   6
```

For notational simplicity, denotes [image]  the i-th row of `Race_ID` r and column `a`, [image] the j-th row of `Race_ID` r and column `b`, etc.

So for example
[image]=3, [image]=2, [image]=1, [image]=4, [image] = 2, [image] =3, [image] =1 and so on.

I want to add a new column called `sum` which is a complicated double sum of other columns for each `Race_ID` defined by the formula

[image]

,where `i` is the current row we are at, and each sum is taken over the Students for each `Race_ID`, so for example n_RACEID = 4,3 for `Race_ID` = 1,2 respectively.

So for example, for row 1 of Race_ID =1 (i.e. r=1, i=1), the sum equals (superscript r obmited for simplicity)

a_2(b_3+b_4) +      <- for k=2

a_3(b_2+b_4) +      <- for k=3

a_4(b_2+b_3)        <- for k=4

= 2(4+1) + 1(2+1) + 4(2+4) = 10+3+24 = 37 and so on and so fourth.

So the desired output looks like

```
Race_ID   Date           Student_ID      a   b   sum 
1         1/1/2023       1               3   1   2(4+1)+1(2+1)+4(2+4)=37
1         1/1/2023       2               2   2   3(4+1)+1(1+1)+4(1+4)=37
1         1/1/2023       3               1   4   3(2+1)+2(1+1)+4(1+2)=25 
1         1/1/2023       4               4   1   3(2+4)+2(1+4)+1(1+2)=31

2         11/9/2022      1               2   6   3(6)+1(2)=20 
2         11/9/2022      2               3   2   2(6)+1(6)=18
2         11/9/2022      3               1   6   2(2)+3(6)=22
```

I know it looks very complicated. I tried to do it using `groupby` and defining functions like a_kb_j and use `apply` and `sum` but it didn't work and it seems the main difficulty is the fact that there are two dummy variables (namely k and j)
Please help, any help is highly appreciated, thanks.

Edit: the function in my actual dataset is not f(k,j)=a_kb_j and is quite a bit more complicated. I simplified it here just for demonstration purpose. Hence the answer should not exploit the "separable" property of the function f(k,j)=a_kb_j=g(k)h(j) to split the sum into two independent summands. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Your example is a bit ambiguous, could you use unique numbers in a and b for clarity? At the moment, there are several 1, 2, 4 so it's unclear which one you are referring to

Comment: Hi @mozway I just updated the notation and add an extra index for Race_ID as superscript, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Race_ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 
        'Date': ['1/1/2023', '1/1/2023', '1/1/2023', '1/1/2023', '11/9/2022', '11/9/2022', '11/9/2022'], 
        'Student_ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3], 
        'a': [3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 1], 
        'b': [1, 2, 4, 1, 6, 2, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def compute_sum(row, df):
    Race_ID = row['Race_ID']
    n_RaceID = df[df['Race_ID'] == Race_ID]['Student_ID'].nunique()
    k_values = df[(df['Race_ID'] == Race_ID) & (df['Student_ID'] != row['Student_ID'])]['a'].values
    j_values = df[(df['Race_ID'] == Race_ID) & (df['Student_ID'] != row['Student_ID'])]['b'].values
    sum_ = sum([k_values[k] * j_values[j] for k in range(len(k_values)) for j in range(len(j_values)) if k != j])
    return sum_

df['sum'] = df.apply(lambda row: compute_sum(row, df), axis=1)

print(df)
```

which will give you

```
   Race_ID       Date  Student_ID  a  b  sum
0        1   1/1/2023           1  3  1   37
1        1   1/1/2023           2  2  2   37
2        1   1/1/2023           3  1  4   25
3        1   1/1/2023           4  4  1   31
4        2  11/9/2022           1  2  6   20
5        2  11/9/2022           2  3  2   18
6        2  11/9/2022           3  1  6   22
```

But, as @mozway points out in his comment, you should beware of ambiguity.

**EDIT**:

If you dtaframe is large, one way to do this is to modify the function to compute on rows to free memry:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Race_ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 
        'Date': ['1/1/2023', '1/1/2023', '1/1/2023', '1/1/2023', '11/9/2022', '11/9/2022', '11/9/2022'], 
        'Student_ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3], 
        'a': [3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 1], 
        'b': [1, 2, 4, 1, 6, 2, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def compute_sum(row, df):
    Race_ID = row['Race_ID']
    n_RaceID = df.groupby('Race_ID')['Student_ID'].nunique()[Race_ID]
    k_values = df.loc[(df['Race_ID'] == Race_ID) & (df['Student_ID'] != row['Student_ID']), 'a']
    j_values = df.loc[(df['Race_ID'] == Race_ID) & (df['Student_ID'] != row['Student_ID']), 'b']
    sum_ = sum([k_values.iloc[k] * j_values.iloc[j] for k in range(len(k_values)) for j in range(len(j_values)) if k != j])
    return sum_

df['sum'] = df.apply(lambda row: compute_sum(row, df), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! The code works, but my original dataframe is very large (about 500,000 Race_ID) and the code takes quite long to execute (few hours). I would like to ask is there any way to do it computationally efficiently? Thanks!

Comment: @Ishigami I added an EDIT to answer your question.